# Having troubles with EXISTS and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, exists

I've been working with this for a while can I can't find a soultion, so maybe you can help me out.

I have a table with 3 columns 'id' 'product' 'code', a product can be repeated but a code must be unique for each product. This is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`id` int, `product` varchar(10), `code` int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`id`, `product`, `code`)
VALUES
    (1, 'product1', 1),
    (2, 'product1', 2),
    (3, 'product1', 3),
    (4, 'product2', 2),
    (5, 'product2', 3),
    (6, 'product3', 1),
    (7, 'product3', 3)
;
```

So what I'm trying to do is a list of cases, if a product has code 1 and code 2, show certain value in a response column, if the product has only code 1 show another value, if the product has code 2 then other value and if the product has neither code 1 nor code 2 then show another value (the code 3 is irrelevant in this example).

This is what I go so far

```
select product, 
    case 
    when exists(select 1 from table1 where code=1) = 1
        and exists(select 1 from table1 where code=2) = 1
    then 'Types are  : 1,2'
    when exists(select 1 from table1 where code=1) = 1
        and exists(select 1 from table1 where code=2) = 0
    then 'Type is  : 1'
    when exists(select 1 from table1 where code=1) = 0
        and exists(select 1 from table1 where code=2) = 1
    then 'Type is  : 2'
    else
        'There are no types 1 or 2'
    end as response
from table1
group by product
```

The problem is that resultset only shows 'Types are  : 1,2' in my response column for product1, product2 and product3, I believe that in the subselect is searching for all products (and not for each product) so is always true that code 1 and code 2 exist.

Any help or direction you could provide will be very welcome.

Thanks for reading.

Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25eb55/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subqueries are searching the whole table for the code you're interested in, not just rows with the same product.

You need to use a *correlated subquery* if you want the subquery to be evaluated against only rows with the same product.

```
select p.product, 
    case 
    when exists(select 1 from table1 where code=1 and product=p.product) = 1
        and exists(select 1 from table1 where code=2 and product=p.product) = 1
    then 'Types are  : 1,2'
    when exists(select 1 from table1 where code=1 and product=p.product) = 1
        and exists(select 1 from table1 where code=2 and product=p.product) = 0
    then 'Type is  : 1'
    when exists(select 1 from table1 where code=1 and product=p.product) = 0
        and exists(select 1 from table1 where code=2 and product=p.product) = 1
    then 'Type is  : 2'
    else
        'There are no types 1 or 2'
    end as response
from table1 as p
group by product
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------------+
| product  | response         |
+----------+------------------+
| product1 | Types are  : 1,2 |
| product2 | Type is  : 2     |
| product3 | Type is  : 1     |
+----------+------------------+
```

However, I usually avoid correlated subqueries because they are so costly for performance. MySQL has to re-execute the subquery for each row in the outer query.

Here's an alternative query that uses no subqueries but gives the same result:

```
SELECT product,
  CASE GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN code IN (1,2) THEN code ELSE NULL END ORDER BY code)
  WHEN '1' THEN 'Type is  : 1'
  WHEN '1,2' THEN 'Types are: 1,2'
  WHEN '2' THEN 'Type is  : 2'
  ELSE 'There are no types 1 or 2'
  END AS response
FROM table1
GROUP BY product
```

Comment: Definitely way faster, I was worried about performance but not anymore.